# Moving QT C++ folder out of existing project to make a new project, problems with PRO file paths

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake

Working on some legacy code that has a big C++ QT project with many subfolders, where some subfolders build into libraries and others into applications.  One of the folders is a kind of experiment that I want to move out of there into a separate "Sandbox" folder still inside the overall GIT repo.

What the project structure looks like:

```
RootOfGitCheckout
|
- Old
  |
  - Somelib
  - Another
  - Experiment
  - Etc
  - Blah
```

What I would like it to look like

```
RootOfGitCheckout
|
- Old
|  |
|  - Somelib
|  - Another
|  - Etc
|  - Blah
|
- Sandbox
  |
  - Experiment
```

Nothing in those other folders depends on Experiment in any way, builds fine when I remove it from the folder structure and Old.pro.  Experiment has own source code and imports some classes defined in the other folders.  The files it imports have all kinds of other dependencies with very tight coupling all over the place.  But I figure since it's all one-way into Experiment, I should be ok, right?

In Experiment.pro I do

```
include(../../old/old.pro) # I added this line when I moved it out
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += \
     ../../old \ # I added this line when I moved it out
     src # existing Experiment src
```

When I try to build Experiment it complains that
`Cannot find file: /home/<user>/RootOfGitCheckout/Sandbox/Somelib/whatever/whatever.pro`

Somelib/whatever/whatever.pro does exist, it's under Old, and Old has no issue finding it when it builds.
I figure I'm missing something fundamental but neither the documentation nor searching is helping.

Since it is complaining about Somelib I thought maybe it's a problem explicit to that so I commented out or made it be the second thing listed in Old.pro instead of first, and the complaint just changed to be about the next one that is listed in Old.pro SUBDIRS.  So it's not something specific about Somelib, it's more general.

Comment: Why are you both including and subdir-ing old.pro? Including .pro files is rarely useful and in this case I suspect old.pro would collide with itself in fun ways.

Comment: @sixtyten because I don't know what I'm doing and figured if I imported the other .pro files I'd get all the dependency chains they declared without needing any extra work and when that didn't work I tried setting the subdirs, but that didn't work either so here I am XD

Comment: include() is a source include akin to #include - it's sometimes useful but not a good way to declare a sub-build. Try removing the include and just specifying the old build as subdir, it might work (though I can't guarantee that out-of-tree subdirs will work properly).

Comment: Also by the way it doesn't matter yet for your small project, but specifying .depends for your subdirs usually beats CONFIG+=ordered in terms of speed - but either will work if you care only about the build working right now